# Using linked lists with class

Tags: c++, class, oop, linked-list

Here is an example of a code sent to me as a help. I did understand a few things, although I am now not sure whether should I have setters and getters for every variable I create?

The program I am working on has so many variables because its a program to store information and stuff. And if isn't too much is it alright if anyone can simplify it? If its impossible at this state it's alright.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
//This is the class to be used
//as a node in the linked list.
class Node
{
    //this are private members,
    //since they are declared as private
    //they can only be accessed by this class
    //which will ensure data security :) (this is called encapsulation)
    private:
        int id;
        string name;
        Node *next;

    //This are public member functions
    //These functions are the only way to access
    //the data members of the Node class
    public:
        //These function are called setter/mutators
        void setId(int);//this function will set the id data member
        void setName(string);//this function will set the name data member
        void setNext(Node*);//this function will set the next pointer

        //These functions are called getters/accessors
        int getId();//this function will get/return the value of the id data member
        string getName();//this function will get/return the value of the name data member
        Node* getNext();//this function will get/return the address of the next node
}*head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

//This function will traverse the linked list.
//It is placed outside the class because it is not needed
//to be one of the class function members 
void traverse(Node*);

int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    //variable declarations for inputs
    int inputData;
    string inputName;

    while(response == 'y')//this will loop the input phase
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Enter ID: ";
        cin>>inputData;
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter name: ";
        getline(cin,inputName);
        //Note about the dot (.) operator and the arrow (->)
        //operator: the dot operator is used when accessing
        //structure or class members without using a pointer,
        //while the arrow operator is used to access structure
        //or class members when using pointers
        Node *node = new Node;
        node->setId(inputData);//calls the setId member function
        node->setName(inputName);//calls the setName member function
        node->setNext(NULL);//calls the setNext member function
        if(head==NULL)
        {   
            head = node;
        }

        if(tail==NULL)
        {
            tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->setNext(node);
            tail = node;
        }

        cout<<"Enter another?: ";
        cin>>response;
    }
    traverse(head);
    return 0;
}




//Here are the function members definitions
void Node::setId(int id)
{
    this->id = id;
}



void Node::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}



void Node::setNext(Node *next)
{
    this->next = next;
}



int Node::getId()
{
    return this->id;
}



string Node::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}



Node* Node::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}



//This is the function definition of the traverse function
void traverse(Node *node)
{
    system("cls");
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"ID: "<<node->getId()<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: "<<node->getName()<<endl<<endl;
        node = node->getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Internal linked list or external ie. std::list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, what do you need here. But if you are looking to use a class based implementation (as opposed to the functional C way) of linked list `std::list` is your key. Bare minimum code showing how two elements are added and traversed using for-each loop is provided below:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::list<int> my_list;
    my_list.push_back(12);
    my_list.push_back(34);

    for(const auto i: my_list){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you are just getting started with C++, it's highly recommended that you devote some time in reading a good C++ book. C++ Primer 5th Edition (Not Primer plus) is typically a good book for beginners.

Comment: I wanted to know how to implement linked lists in object oriented programming. I have a program created but it is using struct. This time i want to use class, since its a task given to us in my uni. Thank btw for the suggestion.

Comment: @NewBee if your university class is requiring you to implement your own linked list class (a common task in a programming class), then surely you know *something* about C++. If you want help with an implementation, you have to post your existing code. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I hope youll get notified with this comment. I have edited the question and I aligned with the guidelines from the link you sent me. I have there an example of the code sent to me as help. Although i couldnt quite figure if i really need a setter and getter for each variable i create for the program. Thank you so much. Hope to hear a positive response.